# How to create an editable textbox?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I am trying to create a textbox that is editable if the user clicks on an image. The textbox is below the image and when the user click away from the textbox it saves.

This is my html

```
 <div id = "folderlist">
 <a  href="linkgoeshere"<image  src="${resource(dir: 'images', file:  'folderimg.png')}" width="100px" height="100px"/>
                <textarea class="captionText" rows="1">${d.name}</textarea>
            </a>
```

Css

`#folderlist{

```
/*font-size: 0;*/
width: 1500px;
margin: 20px auto;
position: absolute;
top: 21%;
right: 8.1%;
text-align: center;
}
```

The problem is as I have each image as link to to somewhere else when the user click on the textarea it redirects them.
Each textarea has to be with its icon so I can move it from the `<a>` tags

**For the purpose of this question I just need to save for that html page, I  can handle the actual permanent saving myself.

I just want the user to be able to click on the image, then the textbox allows the user to edit the text and then when they click away it stays as what they have changed it to(by click away it should call a javascript function which is where I can permanently save it ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created the JS fiddle code for your case. This is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/dhiviyad/b1oka3df/

```js
$(document).on('click touch', '#folderlist .captionText', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('clicking text');
});

$(document).on('click touch', '#folderlist #myImage', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#folderlist .captionText')
    .removeAttr('readonly')
    .focus();
  console.log('clicking img');
});


$(document).on('blur', '#folderlist .captionText', function(e) {
  console.log('blurring text - please save me to server');
  $(this).attr('readonly', 'true')
  saveToServer($(this).val());
  //call function to save to server here
});

function saveToServer(updatedText) {
  console.log('Updated text to send to server', updatedText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="folderlist">
  <a href="test.com">
    <image id='myImage' src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" />
    <textarea class="captionText" rows="1" readonly>d.name</textarea>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, how can I make it so that when a user double clicks the image it goes to the href? i.e test.com?

Comment: @hat_to_the_back, I've added an extra event handler to do that. Updated fiddle code link: https://jsfiddle.net/dhiviyad/b1oka3df/6/

Comment: Basically just add this to the JS: 

$(document).on('dblclick', '#folderlist #myImage', function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 window.location.href = 'test.com';
});

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use an `a` tag, first of all. Just use `onclick`.

Set your `textarea` to `disabled` until you get a click, then use the `onblur` to disable it again when it loses focus.

```
 <div id = "folderlist">
    <image  src="whatever.jpg" onclick="editCaption(this.parentNode.id)" width="100px" height="100px"/>
    <textarea class="captionText" rows="1" onblur="disableText(this)" disabled>some text</textarea>
 </div>


 <script>
    function editCaption(objId) {
        $('#'+objId + " .captionText").prop('disabled', false);
    }

    function disableText(caption) {
        $(caption).prop('disabled', true);
        //your code to save the changes here
    }
 </script>
</html>
```